# qmake QMAKE_EXTRA_TARGETS with VS2010

Tags: qmake

could you help me in this simple case?
My pro file:

```
wordparser.target = generated_source
wordparser.commands = build.bat
wordparser.depends = FORCE
wordparser.CONFIG = recursive
QMAKE_EXTRA_TARGETS += wordparser
PRE_TARGETDEPS += wordparser
TEMPLATE = vcapp
TARGET = demo
SOURCES = stub_test.cpp
```

build.bat generates lots of files that are not used in demo target building. This pro file generates vcxproj which doesn't contain any pre-build events. How do I force build.bat be executed on pre-build step in VS2010?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can't be done with qmake pro files. Pre-build actions are not supported by qmake

Use cmake instead.

Comment: This is wrong... You can use the system(..) call! Shall I submit an answer?

Comment: I'd be pleased. Still don't see how to do this.

Comment: Please try `system(build.bat)`. Does that work? I will submit an answer if it does.

Comment: Are you sure you understood the question? From where should I call system?

Comment: Are you sure that you understand what `system` is? Please just follow my advice and trust me. I will explain later. Put it anywhere, but preferably at the beginning of the project file.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot the case. The real problem was that bat file should be called each time the build is initiated. The system will be called only when qmake is called.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67774/discussion-between-mor-and-lpapp).

Comment: Is this specific to VS2010 ? Is it still true with latest versions of qmake ?